# MongoDB bind_ip not workig with aws elastic ip and 127.0.0.1?

Tags: database, mongodb

I have tried to bind_ip in mongodb.conf file. my MongoDB Version is 3.6. I have installed Ubuntu18.04.

mongodb.log:

```
this is the error log from var/mongodb/mongodb.log:
    2020-03-05T05:31:13.642+0000 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
    2020-03-05T05:31:13.648+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=9307 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit ho$
    2020-03-05T05:31:13.648+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.3
    2020-03-05T05:31:13.648+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 9586e557d54ef70f9ca4b43c26892cd55257e1a5
    2020-03-05T05:31:13.648+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
    2020-03-05T05:31:13.648+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
    2020-03-05T05:31:13.649+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
    2020-03-05T05:31:13.649+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
    2020-03-05T05:31:13.649+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
    2020-03-05T05:31:13.649+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
    2020-03-05T05:31:13.649+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongodb.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1,3.19.5$
    2020-03-05T05:31:13.651+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Cannot assign requested addr$
    2020-03-05T05:31:13.651+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
    2020-03-05T05:31:13.651+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:48
```

mongodb.conf

`bind_ip=127.0.0.1,3.19.59.3
port = 27017`

I have tried like:

`bind_ip=[127.0.0.1,3.19.59.3]
bind_ip=[127.0.0.1 3.19.59.3]
bind_ip=127.0.0.1 3.19.59.3`

but still, I can not access it from my server.

Comment: I believe ServerFault or dba.stackexchange might be a more suitable forum for this question.

Answer (score 0):

`127.0.0.1`  is the IP address of the `localhost` and which is only accessible from the same machine.
could you change bindIp to the following format

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

> DO NOT DO THIS UNLESS YOU HAVE CLIENT AUTHENTICATION ENABLED

Answer (score 0):

According to [net Options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/index.html#net-options) it should be

```
bind_ip: 127.0.0.1,3.19.59.3 
# or
bind_ip: localhost,3.19.59.3
```

(no brackets, No spaces, only comma separated)

However, according to [Fix bindIp multiple address notation in Configuration Options](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-10931)

it should be

```
bindIp: [127.0.0.1,3.19.59.3]
```

I remember,in the past I had the same issue. At the end I gave up and used `bindIp: 0.0.0.0` - of course with authentication and proper firewall settings.